# MVC.net 2 - change the HTML outputed by ValidationMessageFor - can this be down via templates?

Tags: c#, html, validation, asp.net-mvc

MVC.net 2 by default outputs validation messages like this:

```
<span id="UserName_validationMessage" class="field-validation-valid">A Validation message</span>
```

I would like it to do it like this:

```
<label id="UserName_validationMessage" class="field-validation-valid">A Validation message</label>
```

Is there a way to do it like the display and editor templates? Or is there another way to do it globally?

Answer (score 3):

The code that generates that html is inside of ValidateExtensions.cs, in System.Web.Mvc.  You could update the code to output a label instead of a span and then recompile that.  The code looks like the following:

```
        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("span");
        builder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        builder.MergeAttribute("class", HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageCssClassName);
        builder.SetInnerText(String.IsNullOrEmpty(validationMessage) ? GetUserErrorMessageOrDefault(htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext, modelError, modelState) : validationMessage);
```

Otherwise, you might be able to override ValidationExtensions.ValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string message, IDictionary htmlAttributes) and do it that way...

Comment: Modifying an actively developed dll to add your own custom code is a poor choice as it creates added work (and introduces broken behaviour) if the dll is ever updated from the official source.  I'm still looking for a global way of plugging into the behaviour and overriding it, but failing that, I'd just create a custom html helper and output my own markup by copying and customizing the logic from System.Web.Mvc into my own codebase.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you're looking for:

http://blog.syntaxc4.net/?p=711

Comment: The link doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, a gist that is supposed to appear in that page is no longer embedded (probably due to an API change for embedding gists).  This is an excellent example of why link-only answers are a bad idea and content should be copied.  Reading the article, it sounds like author used Regex to solve the issue, so I'd wager he created an extension to use on the result of ValidationMessageFor which ran a regex against the html output and replaced span with label... which, actually, is not what the OP requested.