# Template for ValidationMessage

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

MVC now contains a lot of stuff that you can ovrride using templates, you could override UI representation of any model's field based on any rule and its great. But why I couldn't do the same for the validation message, I suppose it would give developers more flexibility and convience. I know what I could use overriding of Extensions methods just like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationMessage(this HtmlHelper Html, string Model)
   {
     return System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessage(Html, Model);
   }
```

But as long with this one I should also override ValidationMessageFor, also it is divert from the general implementation of html code templating for MVC.

Question: that is the best practise to solve problem of this kind?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to just modify the text of the error? What is it exactly that you want to achieve by overriding ValidationMessage?

Answer (score 1):

When I've needed to customise my ValidationMessageFor elements, I've used css to target the rendered  tag.

The only templates I'm aware of are EditorTemplates and DisplayTemplates - which require "EditorFor" and "DisplayFor" respectively. ValidationMessageFor is hard coded.

I did find some posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221190/custom-validationmessagefor-template) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820471/mvc-net-2-change-the-html-outputed-by-validationmessagefor-can-this-be-down), which should help you write your own method.